# Expired Certificate Error when using MS Graph python API

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working through the MS python tutorial on [building a python app using the Graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python-app-only?tabs=aad). However, when trying to retrieve a client token, I get an error stating the certificate for "login.microsoftonline.com" has expired?

```
"""Simple test script to obtain app-only security token from Azure AD"""

import configparser
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication


# get credentials from config file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(["config.cfg"])

CONFIG = config["azure"]
SCOPE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'

# Initialize ConfidentialClientApplication
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=CONFIG["clientId"],
    client_credential=CONFIG["clientSecret"],
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{CONFIG['tenantId']}"
)

# Acquire a token
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[SCOPE])
access_token = result['access_token']
print("Access Token:", access_token)
```

This results in the following:

```
ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Cannot connect to host
login.microsoftonline.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: 
(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: 
certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)')]
```

Going to https://login.microsoftonline.com in a browser works just fine, so I'm not sure what I did wrong - any pointers would be greatly appreciated ...

**Update**

The problem is SSL certificate related. Disabling verification in the app call changes the error into a warning:

```
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=CONFIG["clientId"],
    client_credential=CONFIG["clientSecret"],
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{CONFIG['tenantId']}",
    verify=False,
)
```

Which throws the warning:

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'login.microsoftonline.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```

The [url3 lib docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/user-guide.html#ssl) offer a solution that allows for making verified requests using `http.request` without issue, but I'm not sure how to adapt it with the `msal` library?

Comment: I would image this has something to do with the file `config.cfg` not containing the correct/expected credentials.

Comment: The credentials & app registration check out, I was able to narrow it down to the certificate chain (updated original post with more info).